# How to efficiently get a number of words from a text using perl?

Tags: perl

I need to  get the first ~50 words from a text for suplying exerpt to the users of my application.
I did the following:

```
use strict;use warnings;use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
my $text = <<TXT;
Регулярните изрази ни позволяват да търсим шаблони в данните си. 
Повечето букви и символи просто ще съвпадат със самите себе си. 
Например, регулярният израз "test" просто и точно ще съвпада със 
символния низ "test". Можете да включите режим, 
нечувствителен към разликата между малки и големи букви, който ще 
позволи да съвпадне също така и с "Test" или "TEST". Има изключения от 
това правило, някои символи са особени и не съвпадат със 
самите себе си. Вместо това те сигнализират... 
TXT

my $c = 0;
my $collected = substr($text, 0, 10);
while ($text =~ /$collected/) {
    $c += 10;
    $collected = substr($text, 0, $c);
    print $collected, $/;
    #sleep 1;
    my @words = split(/\s+/, $collected);

    if (@words >= 49) { last; }
}
```

this works fine but I am concerned about the efficiency of the code.

Imagine that I havto do the same for many, many texts.
There should be a smarter more perlish way, but I can not figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = <<TXT;
Регулярните изрази ни позволяват да търсим шаблони в данните си. 
Повечето букви и символи просто ще съвпадат със самите себе си. 
Например, регулярният израз "test" просто и точно ще съвпада със 
символния низ "test". Можете да включите режим, 
нечувствителен към разликата между малки и големи букви, който ще 
позволи да съвпадне също така и с "Test" или "TEST". Има изключения от 
това правило, някои символи са особени и не съвпадат със 
самите себе си. Вместо това те сигнализират... 
TXT

my @words = $text =~ m/ \s* ( \S+ ) /gmsx;
$#words = 49;
print "@words\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you define a "word" as "\S", you could do something like this:

```
$words = $1 if $text=~/^\s*((?:\S+(?:\s+|$)){0,50})/;
```

Comment: That drops the last word if there are 50 words or less.

Comment: @ikegami: Only if your text doesn't end in a newline. But easily fixed, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could get all the words then remove the excess as in shawnhcorey's solution, or you could stop when you have enough.

```
my @words;
push @words, $1 while @words < 50 && $text =~ /\s*(\S+)/g;
```

**Update**: Removed bad solution.